# Using same views multiple times in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have an `Activity` which also has a `ListView` in it. I'm loading some `EditText` boxes, buttons, etc to that `ListView` in my `getView` method.

```
if(position==0)
            {
                ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_settings)).setText("User Information");

            }
            else if(position==1 || position==2 || position==5 || position==6 || position==7 || position==10 || position==13)
            {
                ((LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.linear_settings)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Relative_home)).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if(position==1 || position==5 || position==5)
                    ((EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_settings)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f_t_1_iphone);
                else if(position==7 || position==2)
                    ((EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_settings)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f_t_3_iphone);
                else if(position==6)
                    ((EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_settings)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f_t_2_repeat_iphone);
                else if(position==13 || position==10)
                    ((EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_settings)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f_t_4_iphone);    
            }
```

And in multiple instances I'm also adding a `Button` to the same `List`. Basically, I'm just loading a particular layout file to a particular row based on the row index of the `ListView`. The button has the id `button_title` - defined in my xml below.

```
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.next, null); *//inside getView method*
```

Contents of next.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear">

    <FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/frame_settings">

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Relative_home"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Button_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:background="@drawable/edit_button_pressed" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
     </RelativeLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_settings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">       
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_settings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
     </FrameLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Now, since I have multiple instances of the same button within this activity, I'm not able to assign unique IDs to each of these buttons. All buttons technically now hold the same ID.

Is there any way in which I can assign different IDs to each of these buttons? Programmatically?

Comment: means u want to change id of button which u have used in custome  listview layout next.xml

Comment: yes. That is what I intend to do.

Comment: is there any reason to do that plz provide why u want that and which action u want to perfome on that bases etc

Comment: I have 3 edittext boxes which are disabled until I click "edit" button for each Edittext box. Once I click "edit" button, the edittext box will be enabled and I will be able to edit it. I am re-using the layout for each row. That is why I need different IDs.

Comment: If you only have 3 rows, then you don't really gain much by reusing the rows. I would just create each row of its own, which makes it a lot easier to control and handle, because you can assign each item a custom ID in your xml-file

Comment: @banzai86 I agree with your point. I have 5 -6 rows and as it is my app is memory intensive. I thought defining a new layout for each row would increase the overhead.

Comment: I think it starts to make a notable difference if your Listview grows to 50+ rows

Comment: ok, But I have already implemented the solution described below. Thanks for the info though!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use findViewById on the buttons parent layout in order to change the id on the specific button.

Egs:

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.next, null);
Button buttonIWantToChangeID = convertView.findViewById(R.whatever.Button_title);
buttonIWantToChangeID.setId(1000+listPosition);
```

Notice findViewById is used on the convertView...

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can change the id of a view

```
Button button = context.findViewById(R.whatever.button);
button.setId();// <-- put the new id as the param
```

NOTE: make sure you don't have any conflicting ids!!

Comment: Hi John. This will again result in changing the ID of the button for all instances. Meaning where ever I've used that button, I will still end up with same IDs repeating.

Comment: Can you edit your question and make it more detailed? I'm having trouble understanding it, it seems kind of ambiguous.